# Does anyone know how to deploy flask app on IPage?

Tags: python, flask

I have searched everywhere and cant find anything on how to do it, all I know is it's possible. Please help.

Comment: ...What's IPage?

Comment: IPage is a website hosting company [IPage.com](http://ipage.com)

Comment: @derek do see my answer. I have only deployed django apps, so you need to apply the similar steps for Flask. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask is not currently installed on the iPage servers.  Since iPage does not allow users to have shell logins you will not be able to install Flask yourself.  (You can ask iPage if they are willing to install it.)

Python (V 2.6.4) is installed on the iPage server along with Django (V 1.1.1) so that is an alternate option for you depending on what you are trying to do.

Here is the code I used to check what was on the server.  I just uploaded this code into the "cgi-bin" folder on my iPage web page in a file named "test.py".  Then I looked at the web page www.MY_WEB_PAGE_NAME/cgi-bin/test.py  The page showed the version of Python, Django and Flask if they are loaded.  Flask was not loaded by the script, an error message "No module named flask" indicated it is not installed on the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import traceback
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head>"
print "<title>CGI Test</title>"
print "</head><body>"
print "<H1>Test page using Python</H1>"

VERSION = sys.version_info
print "<br> Python Version:"
print VERSION
print "<br>"

try:
    import django
    print "<br> Django Version:"
    print django.VERSION
    print "<br>"
except:
    print "<br> Django was not loaded here is the traceback:<br>"
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print "<br>"

try:
    import flask
    print "<br> Flask Version:"
    print flask.__version__
    print "<br>"    
except:
    print "<br> Flask was not loaded here is the traceback:<br>"
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print "<br>"

print "</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask/Django applications are supported only in the `VPS and Dedicated hosting plans` and not in the `shared hosting platform`.

**This was their response when I asked them about deploying a Django application on their server**

> Normally we do not support the installation of application from our end.
>   It can be installed manually from your end with the help of your Web
>   master or web developer .  You can know more on installing django  on
>   server by referring instructions provided at:
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/install/

You would deploy the application just as how you would do on any other web hosting server.
So all I did was:

1. SSH to the server - please see my comment about this
2. Installed Django (In your case Flask)
3. Installed dependencies (e.g. if you have requiremtns.txt file)
4. Ran `Python manage.py runserver` for django

Follow the similar steps for Flask and you should be able to deploy it.

Comment: I cant quite figure out how to ssh in to ipage I googled it and google said ssh is not supported with ipage can you give me some help with that?

Comment: Sorry. I got confused with another web hosting service. I haven't used `ipage` in a while and without an account i can't access their control panel but I do recall that it was done by accessing the sample scripts section, see a similar example [here](https://www.hostingreviewbox.com/features/ipage-php/).

Comment: Essentially what you need is to open up some sort of a console/shell in the `ipage` control panel section and then follow the requires steps

Comment: It turns out I cant access any type of shell or console with ipage :( So looks like I will have to make this app out of php and ajax, thanks for the help though!

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information